# DAOs with spring JDBC templates : Best way to unit test

Tags: unit-testing

What is the best way to unit/integration test DAO layer classes built using Spring JDBC templates?

Three approaches come to mind:

1) Mock library (EasyMock, JMock, Mockito, etc) - Spring framework test code makes use of this approach - They use EasyMock.

2) Embedded Database (H2, HSQL, Derby)

3) Real Database - Same product as used in production, Sybase ASE in my case - different schema obviously.

```
Cons:
1)This may slow down unit test execution.
2)Schema is shared between different developers / CI server. So, need to make sure there is no concurrency issue.
```

Some people argue that First and Second approaches are not real testing. Additional problem with Second approach is that, the database I use, Sybase ASE doesn't seem compatible with any of them.

Would like to know best practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- If you do not do #1, you are not really unit testing.
- Our DAOs in general are very thin and do not need unit testing, but we heavily integration test them and we do it with an embedded database (H2).
- #3 does not seem like a good idea. As far as I understand you are talking about using a single 'real database' that is shared between tests. This can cause you a lot of headaches and is very unmaintainable! Tests need to run in isolation!

Comment: With Option 2 (Using Embedded Database) - how can one work with Sybase ASE database? H2 doesn't have Sybase compatibility mode.

Comment: @tapasvi: it does not need to be an embedded database necessary. In our project everyone has a database locally so integration tests can run against that. Is that achievable for you?